# How to pipe unbuffered data from STDOUT to ServerResponse?

Tags: node.js

How can I pipe the unbuffered output from the child process to HTTP.ServerResponse?

The Node.js code below does work for *buffered* output, but not for *unbuffered* output.

```
var http = require('http'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        var ping = spawn("ping", ["127.0.0.1"]);
        ping.stdout.pipe(res);
        ping.stderr.pipe(res);
        req.connection.on('end', function() {
            ping.kill();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the output from `ping 127.0.0.1`:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

Since `ping` writes request timeouts to STDOUT as *unbuffered* data, the code above only works if `ping` is successful.

I'm using Node.js v0.8.19.

Comment: I did not get the problem, are you not able to get the output of ping on client ?

Comment: I'm not able to get ping timeouts on the client. I can get normal ping responses though.

Comment: you mean Request timeout for icmp_seq x is not shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [common problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) that isn't necessarily limited to Node.js.

If you're on Unix, you could use the [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) script, which is part of [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm). Most GNU systems also provide [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html), which lets you do the same thing (although I'm admittedly not very familiar with it).

If you want to use `unbuffer`, you just need to change your above example to:

```
var ping = spawn("unbuffer", ["ping", "127.0.0.1"]);
```

If you're on Windows, things are quite a bit more difficult, as Windows does not natively provide any sort of equivalent to a `PTY`.  Projects such as [winpty](https://github.com/peters/winpty) (and its JavaScript binding, [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/)) attempt to re-create this functionality using the [Windows Console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx), although I've found their implementation to be somewhat buggy and incomplete.

[ActiveState's win32 Expect package](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/expect) isn't the easiest thing to install, and doesn't include the `unbuffer` script in the default distribution.  However, if you manage to get everything working and make a few small modifications to the Unix `unbuffer` script, you should be able to compile an `unbuffer` executable, which you can then call from Node.

Comment: +1,000,000 if I could. I was nearly ready to stream my fist into my computer. `unbuffer` is the solution! Also (so this comment has some substance), for OSX users with brew installing is easy: `brew install expect`.

Comment: actually I can't get `stdbuf` to work the same as `unbuffer`, can anybody confirm?

Comment: See this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/23420 - it says to run the program in `script -c` which is installed by default, YES!

Answer (score 0):

You are killing the ping process on request connection end which happens as soon as request is recieved successfully on server. ping keeps closing before it can output `Request timeout for icmp_seq 5`.

Try to do something like this

```
var http=require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        var ping = spawn("ping", ["127.0.0.1","-c","20"]);
        ping.stdout.pipe(res);
        ping.stderr.pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Note:
ping goes on forever so you cannot wait for it to end. Use -c to ping x number of times.

Comment: Using -c does force the process to end, at which point the results are received by the client. However, I'd like to get the results as they are in progress (which does work for successful pings).

Comment: response is sent once for a particular request. so you cannot send successive results as they come after sending the first response. To stream the results, you will have to use socket.io ,this will help you to communicate in realtime between server and client.

Comment: That is incorrect. The server can continue to send more data back to the client for as long as the connection is in place. You can see this behavior with successful pings.

Comment: You are confusing response stream and HTTP response. HTTP response is sent once, which is shown by the browser that time. stream allows you to write more data but it is only sent to browser after the response stream finishes. so it cannot display results as they come.

Comment: I'm using a command-line CURL client, which uses HTTP Keep-Alive by default. Keep-Alive implements Persistent Connections (defined here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068#section-8) which can be used to send and receive multiple requests and responses on the same connection. Each time a successful ping occurs, the output is piped to the response socket and transmitted to the client immediately, not when the connection is finished. Unfortunately, this isn't the case for unsuccessful pings because the output of unsuccessful pings is unbuffered.