# How to get data from nodejs express to jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-mobile

I have two application one is jquery mobile and the other is nodejs which i am running on background,In jquery mobile i have the functionality of entering ip address(www.google.com), while i click the button called "test connectivity"  it must get the details from the other app nodejs which is running on the background to get the details of what is the ip address,No of packets send and No of packets received.The issue is I am unable to get those details in my text-box of my jquery mobile from nodejs which is running as a separate url.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" data-theme="b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label>Packets Sent</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <label class="send">: </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-a" data-theme="b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label class="received">Packets Received</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <label class="packet">: </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-a" data-theme="b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label style="padding-top:15px">Destination Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <input type="text" id="ipPing" name="url" class="ipPing" placeholder="Enter URL" />
    </div>
</div>
<input class="testip" type="button" data-theme="b" id="urltestsubmit" value="TEST CONNECTIVITY">
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".testip").click(function () {
    var ipaddress = $(".ipPing").val();
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/getperformance/" + ipaddress;
});
```

Node Js:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var spawndata = require('child_process').spawn;
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/getPerformance/:ip', function (req, res) {

    var ip = req.params.ip;

    var ping = spawn("ping", [ip]);
        ping.stdout.pipe(res);
        ping.stderr.pipe(res);

}); http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on *nix, try to add "-c 4" also as parameters, otherwise ping will go on forever.

```
spawn("ping", [ip, "-c", "4"]);
```

Mentioned in: [How to pipe unbuffered data from STDOUT to ServerResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753133/how-to-pipe-unbuffered-data-from-stdout-to-serverresponse) (post at the bottom)